# How to include changes to library in my own app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, libraries

I am using a library which unfortunately has some issues. Now being new to this whole project stuff I'm not sure how to approach this.

Let's just say that library is windows-registry. And I have 2 fixes on the code, line 30 and line 50.

What are my possible and best approaches to do this?

(Note, I'm using an app, and my repo does not have the "library" included, and I am well aware that's the whole point of library).

Should I make my fix on github and just use that fork as library? Is this the best approach?

Comment: I think you should fork the project, do the fix - and do a pull-request so everyone can benefit.

If that is not something that the owner wants, just do a fork and use that - or find a different library that better fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks VisualBean!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should fork the project, do the fix - and do a pull-request so everyone can benefit.

If the above is not something that the owner wants, just do a fork and use that - or find a different library that better fits your needs. :)